# SQL SERVER - GRAB RECORD FROM THE TABLE BASED ON COLUMN ID

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I have a db with records like the  following structure in the table;

```
id,msg,date,fid 
19 ,"hello","2012-02",0
20 ,"hello","2012-03",19
```

I have and entire db set up like this where the fid in some cases matches the id of another record. In that case id like to return one record with 2 different dates such as ;

```
19 ,"hello","2012-02",0,"2012-03"
```

I was thinking a self join but got hung up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes self join is one way

```
   Select distinct t.id,t.msg,t.date, t1.date
   From table t join (Select fid, date from  
   Table) t1 on
    t.id =t1.fid
```

Comment: thank you, however i get an error saying there is incorrect syntax near t1

Comment: Did u change table to your tables name

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t.id,t.msg,t.date_added,t1.date
FROM myTable t
    (JOIN  SELECT date FROM myTable)  t1 
      ON t.id = t1.fid;

Comment: Remove brackets before join add that open bracket after join check my syntax again

Comment: ok i did now its stating invalid column names t1.date and date

Comment: Change date to date_added in whole

Comment: it only works when  give it a where clause now , record is what i need but i need it for all records not just one